# Custom sorting list

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I wanted sort pivot data according to the months and not from A to Z. 
The monthly sorting is not included in my Excel, therefore, I tried to add a custom sorting from the Excel options (options-> advance-> general-> edit custom lists). However, when I click on the edit custom lists tab it doesn't open up and doesn't allow me to create any custom lists.
I have the same problem with sorting data even when it is not in a pivot table.
Any ideas how to solve the problem?

[Excel settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTTyK.png)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Custom+sorting+list+excel) may contain a good reference/solution..

Comment: How about creating a list in Worksheet first and then selecting the list range to Custom list?

Comment: @Lee that is exactly my problem. I cannot create any Custom lists.

Comment: @p._phidot_ thanks I have a look and hopefully find a solution!

Comment: I think we can't recommend a solution coz you didn't share a sample file/screenshot/data.. || You may share these, so that we may proceed here. ( :

Comment: I have sorted my data with the vlookup function. However, I still do not manage to create any new custom lists. Do I need to change anything in the settings (see image)?